# Disable DFP iframes to acces parent window

Tags: iframe, google-dfp

I am having some troubles with malicious ads that show interstitials with no close button.

Inspecting the code, I found that DFP uses `<iframe>` tags to load the ads, but as the content of those iframes are loaded using Javascript (using iframe's `document.write()`, without `src` attribute), they get full access to parent window through `window.top` and `window.top.document`, allowing advertisers to inject code, show malicious ads and even stole data such as user emails and passwords.

In order to prevent this, I'm looking for a way to block DFP ads to access the main window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `SafeFrames` rather than `Friendly Iframes` you appear to be using. Quoting from DFP's [help page](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/183282?hl=en) on the subject:

> We recommend using SafeFrames and creatives compatible with SafeFrame for expansion instead of friendly iframes. SafeFrame is supported in DFP and enabled by default when using GPT tags. It enables transparent and rich interactions between page content and ads, while preventing external access to sensitive data and providing more granular control over which creatives are rendered

Comment: I already did it, using `googletag.pubads().setForceSafeFrame(true);`

Comment: Could you plz post a link to your web page or publish a working example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use synchronous rendering, try to change it to asynchronous

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/183282?hl=en